# Getting Rid of Yellow Fill On Input After Email Auto-Fill From Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, cross-browser

I have a simple username-password form set up with some styles applied to it. It works great. The problem comes when I login more than one time.

Namely, since Chrome recognizes my email, it tries to auto-fill it. If I oblige, the username textbox acquires a repulsive yellow color. See images below for screenshots.

How can I stop this from happening? I have not tested thoroughly, but it seems that neither Firefox nor Safari has this issue.

[image: Empty form]

[image: After auto-fill has occurred.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `:-webkit-autofill` CSS pseudo-class, it matches when an  element has its value autofilled by the browser.

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px white inset !important;
}
```

Comment: Is this Chrome-specific or cross-browser?

Comment: Chrome and Safari !

Comment: Excellent! Thanks.

Comment: If this solves the problem, please mark it as accepted (so people facing the same problem in the future will be able to spot it easily).

Comment: I was going to. Another 6 minutes and then I can ;)